# How to make git branch inside same repo directory

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm working on a simple project using Jekyll and want hosting by Github Pages, but that's not the case here...

I have a directory, say named `myrepo`, and inside it I have all of the Jekyll directory structure (`_data`, `_includes`...), having too a `_src` directory that is not a collection. Now only a branch `gh-pages` is being used, and `_src` is listed in `.gitignore`.
Now I want to create a `master` branch in same repo with the contents of `_src`. I created the repo with the first branch named so I didn't deleted the branch I want to create before.

It is posible to do what I want? If so, how can that be done? P.S.: the contents of `_src` are the `original` ones, and the other in `myrepo` are being generated (not at all, but a few changes are made).

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** To make it clearer, here is the directory tree as suggested:

```
my-repo
|-- _includes
|   |-- head.html
|-- _layouts
|   |-- default.html
|   `-- post.html
|-- _posts
|   |-- 2015-07-08-sample.html
|-- _site
|-- _src
|   |-- _includes
|   |   |-- head.html
|   |-- _layouts
|   |   |-- default.html
|   |   `-- post.html
|   |-- _posts
|   |   |-- 2015-07-08-sample.md
|   |-- _config.yml
|   |-- .gitignore
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- LICENSE
|   `-- README.md
|-- _config.yml
|-- .gitignore
|-- index.html
|-- LICENSE
`-- README.md
```

I just want that everything that is inside `my-repo/` except `src/` to be in a `gh-pages` branch, and the contents of `my-repo/_src/` in `master` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `git checkout -b master`: create a master branch
2. remove _src from the .gitignore and commit the .gitignore file
3. `git add _src` and `git commit`

You are good to go! :)

(if it doesn't work please edit your question with a draft of your directory structure so I can take a closer look at it)

Comment: That worked :) I edited the question to include a directory tree. Now: can I remove all other files (those outside `_src`) from the `master` branch that was created?

Comment: Is valid to create a new git repo inside `_src` and then push it as master to the remote?
I mean: in `my-site` the repo is at `gh-pages` branch, synced with `origin/gh-pages`, and I create a empty Git repo inside `_src` the push it to `master`.

Comment: You can remove the files from the master.

Comment: You can create a nested repo. But you'll need to add the _src folder in the .gitignore of the "outer repo". I don't believe if this is a good choice, but it is possible! :)

Comment: Yeah @Lucas Saldanha, I did that. There must be consequences for example while cloning the repo from another PC but for now it works. Thanks anyway.